# How to read.transactions in R feom data frame?

Tags: r, transactions, apriori, arules

I have a following task. I have 50M of transaction rows. I couldnt export it to .txt file but i have connection with my Hive and i created table with transactions:
Transcation_id Item
1               A
1               B
1               C
2               A
2               A

I cannot use

```
order_trans <- read.transactions(
  file = "(...)/trans2019.csv",
  format = "single",
  header=TRUE,
  sep = ",",
  cols=c("trans_id","item"),
  rm.duplicates = T,
  encoding = "UTF-16LE")
```

because it cuts transactions.

I would likt to do the same but in place of "File" i would like to put my data frame (trans_id,item) but it doesnt work.
I also tried:

`trans = as(data.frame,"transactions")`
but then apriori algorithm gives me wrong rules

APPLE--> transaction_ID

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the solutions from the manual page (see '? transactions'):

```
## example 4: creating transactions from a data.frame with 
## transaction IDs and items (by converting it into a list of transactions first) 
a_df3 <- data.frame(
  TID = c(1,1,2,2,2,3),
  item=c("a","b","a","b","c", "b")
  )
a_df3
trans4 <- as(split(a_df3[,"item"], a_df3[,"TID"]), "transactions")
trans4
inspect(trans4)

## Note: This is very slow for large datasets. It is much faster to 
## read transactions using read.transactions() with format = "single".
## This can be done using an anonymous file.
write.table(a_df3, file = tmp <- file(), row.names = FALSE)
trans4 <- read.transactions(tmp, format = "single",
  header = TRUE, cols = c("TID", "item"))
close(tmp)
inspect(trans4)
```